# How to make Meteor useraccounts:bootstrap button for resetting password to work?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

After receiving the password reset link by email, I click it to land at the password reset page. After filling in the two identical passwords and pressing the "Set Password" button, the page got stuck with elements disabled.

I tried to find the docs for where/how I should customize this button behavior (not sure if I need to do it) so that I end up calling `Accounts.resetPassword`, but I couldn't find it.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been solved by https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core/commit/4749b6b9bd9f1264e3c0009a735b1683c72645bb.

I just needed to upgrage.